# PowerShell : Add a AAD security group to a SharePoint Online sitecollection

Tags: powershell, security, sharepoint-online

I'm wrestling on a way to add a AAD securitygroup as a domain group in SPO site collection, with f.e. contribute rights.

Want to skip all default SharePoint securitygroups.
Using UI, it seems perfectly possible.

[image]

Can't find the right PNP commando and ChatGPT isn't that usefull ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can create an empty SharePoint group and add AD group to the SharePoint group then using PowerShell.

```
#Variables for Admin Center & Site Collection URL
$AdminCenterURL = "https://crescent-admin.sharepoint.com/"
$SiteURL = "https://crescent.sharepoint.com/sites/marketing"
$SPGroupName="Sales Portal Members"
$ADGroupName = "Marketing Managers"

#Connect to SharePoint Online
Connect-SPOService -url $AdminCenterURL -Credential (Get-Credential)

#sharepoint online powershell add group to site
New-SPOSiteGroup -Site $SiteURL -Group $SPGroupName -PermissionLevels "Edit"

Function Add-ADGroupToSP($SiteURL,$ADGroupName,$SPGroupName)
{
    #Setup Credentials to connect
$Cred = Get-Credential
$Cred = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($Cred.UserName,$Cred.Password)

Try {
    #Setup the context
    $Ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteURL)
    $Ctx.Credentials = $Cred
  
    #Get the Web and SharePoint Group
    $Web = $Ctx.Web
    $Group= $Web.SiteGroups.GetByName($SPGroupName)

    #Resolve the AD Security Group
    $ADGroup = $web.EnsureUser($ADGroupName)

    #sharepoint online powershell add AD group to sharepoint group
    $Result = $Group.Users.AddUser($ADGroup)
    $Ctx.Load($Result)
    $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()

    write-host  -f Green "Active Directory Group '$ADGroupName' has been added to '$SPGroupName'"
}
Catch {
    write-host -f Red "Error:" $_.Exception.Message
}
}

Add-ADGroupToSP -SiteURL $SiteURL -ADGroupName $ADGroupName -SPGroupName $SPGroupName
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer Allen. Not exactly what I wanted to do, but there's apparently no way to add a Domain Group toplevel trough PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone was still looking for this
OR for future reference. I think I've found a way.

```
$Teamsite = "https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxx" 
$DomainGroup = "c:0t.c|tenant|Azure AD SG ID"  
$PermissionLevel = "Contribute"      
Connect-pnponline $teamsite -interactive
Set-PnPWebPermission -User $DomainGroup -AddRole $PermissionLevel  -Identity "/"
```